# How convert string "20080926112720" to datetime in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

i am getting the value from xml 20080926172720. I have loaded using ssis as a string column in sql server.but ineed to store 09/26/2008 27:17:20 like this as a datetime in sql server

```
convert(datetime,'20080926112720',101)
```

I need a output like this

```
09/26/2008 11:27:20
```

I'm using SQL Server 2005

Comment: DATE_FORMAT()? What have you tried?

Comment: Try this `$original_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', $date_to_format_string);
$reformated_date = $original_date->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');`

Comment: i used convert(datetime,'20080926271720',101) but its not working..

Comment: Then just use the datetime column....

Comment: @KamalDeepak You state that it is not working, are you getting an error?  Please provide as many details as possible to answer your question.

Comment: @zane Its not accepting in the value

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Comment: @blufeet I got the below error..                                                               Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Comment: @KamalDeepak Are you running this in SQL Server or SSIS?  You initially stated SSIS.

Comment: This converted date i need to use in ssis using derived column..

Comment: DT_DBTIMESTAMP should be the datatype you're looking for.

Comment: Yes..End column should be a timestamp

Comment: Current Timestamp or a certain time in the past?  if you need the current timestamp, use CONVERT(datetime,GETDATE(),101)

Comment: Is this column coming from a variable or is it a hard coded value?

Comment: its coming from variable

Comment: Okay how is the Variable set and why is it a string Value to begin with?

Comment: @KamalDeepak I strongly suggest editing your question to include all the information about your question, including where this is being used, how you are getting the values, etc.  Right now, we are just guessing at how to solve your problem.

Comment: anyone else want to know why he has a 27 hour day?

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer that was my next question because the item fails conversion for that very reason. SSIS is pretty insistent that you have a 24 hour day.

Comment: @blufeet i am getting the value from xml <datetime>20080926172720</datetime>. I have loaded using ssis as a string column in sql server.but ineed to store 09/26/2008 27:17:20 like this as a datetime in sql..

Comment: Date format 101 is CCYY-MM-DD only THAT'S why its failing.  You will need to change your format

Comment: You haven't addressed that fact that you have a 27 hour day. @KamalDeepak that's going to throw a wrench into your conversion my good man.

Comment: 20080926112720 this is  the correct format..

Comment: @KamalDeepak Add those details to your **question**

Comment: No this is the correct format 2008-09-26 11:27:20 if you were to use that you'd be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the cleanest way but SQL is having trouble parsing out the HH:mm:ss without the colon separator.  This way will get you the formatting you want.  I strongly suggest finding a way to make your input to the convert function formatted as 'CCYYMMDD HH:mm:ss'

```
DECLARE @MyDate char(15)
SET @MyDate = '20080926132720'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Mydate,5,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@MyDate,7,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@MyDate,1,4)+SPACE(1)+SUBSTRING(@MyDate,9,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(@MyDate,11,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(@MyDate,13,2)
```

Comment: Ugh now I feel like I've wasted my time on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe I put the amount of time into this that I did but you need to create a new variable and evaluate the variable as an expression to give it the proper formatting. Right now SSIS has no clue how to parse the blurb of text you are giving it. In the expression builder you should build something like this.

```
SUBSTRING( "20080926112720",1, 4 )+"-"+SUBSTRING( "20080926112720",5, 2 )+"-"+SUBSTRING( "20080926112720",7, 2 )+ " "+SUBSTRING( "20080926112720",9, 2 )+ ":"+SUBSTRING( "20080926112720",11, 2 )+":" +SUBSTRING( "20080926112720",13, 2 )
```

This will evaluate to this value `2008-09-26 11:27:20` then you can set that variable as Datetime.
You will of course need to modify this as

```
SUBSTRING( @@YourDateVariable,1, 4 )+"-"+SUBSTRING( @@YourDateVariable,5, 2 )+"-"+SUBSTRING( @@YourDateVariable,7, 2 )+ " "+SUBSTRING( @@YourDateVariable,9, 2 )+ ":"+SUBSTRING( @@YourDateVariable,11, 2 )+":" +SUBSTRING( @@YourDateVariable,13, 2 )
```